# Different models sharing one ID list

Tags: django, django-models, abstract-class, uniqueidentifier

In my application I've added a "Facebook Comment Box" (on different pages, for different objects). Each object has its own comments list so I need to provide a unique (across the site) ID for every single one of them.

What would be the best approach for achieving this: An abstract model, from which all other models will inherit? A dummy model with a ForeignKey relation? What are your ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved with a dummy model :

http://fromzerotocodehero.blogspot.com/2010/11/providing-uniqueness-of-different.html

Answer (score 2):

You may want to implement GUIDs:

http://www.codecommit.com/blog/database/are-guids-really-the-way-to-go

Here's a django module that gives you a field for 'em:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/softwarefabrica.django.utils/

... you can safely use them in URLs -- won't be pretty, but for comments and other things without obvious URL-able titles, GUIDs work out well.